# l can't login with the method l used, l have tried to use the authenticate method but it's not working can someone point me in the right direction

Tags: django, authentication, view

```
def index(request):
#check if username and password POST requests exits (user submitted form)
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']

    user = auth.authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        messages.info(request, "invalid credentials")
        return redirect('index')
else:
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

here is my code l even tried to just use authentication without the auth but same results

Comment: How did you *create* the users?

Comment: okay let me paste how l created the user

Comment: so the below is how l create a user

Comment: please [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Django's `authenticate` will check if the *hashed* version of the password matches with the stored password. Therefore you can not save the password in a raw manner.

The `AbstractBaseUser` class therefore offers a [**`set_password(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser.set_password) that will set the password to the hashed form of the password.

You thus can implement this as:

```
    # …
    else:
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()
        messages.info(request,"Registered Successfully")
```

I would furthermore strongly advise to use a `Form` (or a `ModelForm`) to validate the input data. This is in fact the main task of a `Form`: to validate and clean input, and remove a lot of boilerplate code with respect to validation error messages, cleaning, and saving the object.

Comment: Awesome l used model forms, it worked and  thanks, incase someone run into the same issue check out my GitHub repo

https://github.com/KudzanaiGomera/Hypertube.git